# Is there a better way than twig files overwrite?

Tags: theming, 8, entities

In my project, I have a " field--node--title.html.twig " file, I used this file to overwrite the title label to be able to give it a certain class.

I know you can be more specific using " field--node--title-x.html.twig ", Where x can be a block or a page!

I was wondering if there exists a better way of doing this. Maybe I could do IF conditions inside " field--node--title.html.twig " file to check for a certain block or a certain page.

This would be much easier and it would also decrease the number of files in the field folder in templates.

Comment: I don't think that it is possible

Comment: Making logical decisions in templates is worse, not better. It means less can be cached.

Comment: You can add your own twig suggestions too. Also, big no to doing a lot of logic in twig files.

Comment: @Clive, Kevin, you can implement logic in twig the same as in preprocess. Caching is the same for both. If you base the logic on information outside of the scope of the parent entity you have to include this in the cache metadata.

Comment: @4k4 Caching aside, keeping display and logic separate has been a cornerstone of this kind of development for a long time. You definitely _can_ keep your logic in a template, but best practice usually dictates that you don't. I haven't come across anything that suggests it would be different for Drupal

Comment: @Clive, I think best practice has changed a lot in D8. Logic in twig is simple and easily readable, so why not use it? I think a theme with less php and more twig is not necessarily a bad thing.

Comment: Simple if/else and for are okay, but I was thinking of the potentially large conditions written to check for just one condition listed in the original question - which case might warrant a different strategy to me.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, usually there is a better way: preprocess functions allow you to alter the render array that is passed to the twig template. Adding a class is, in most cases, possible, but you might need to check how the twig file is turning the render array into markup.

This article has more info: https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/theming-drupal-8/modifying-attributes-in-a-theme-file